# Problem with the Glossary+bib2gls on Overleaf

Tags: glossaries, overleaf, glossaries-extra, bib2gls

I'm writing my thesis using [overleaf](http://v2.overleaf.com) and I would like to add Glossary. I have added the following commands to my preamble.tex

```
\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}
\GlsXtrLoadResources % input file created by bib2gls
[% instructions to bib2gls:
src={entries}, % terms defined in entries.bib
sort={en-GB}% sort according to this locale
]
```

I have added `\printunsrtglossaries` just before `\end{document}`  and created `entries.bib` that contains my list
 as instructed by [this guide](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf) (page 24). I receive the following errors when I copmile my file:
[image]
 (swipt) is in my list.

Any idea how to deal with this?

Thanks.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[
% Dummy file for testing example-glossaries-brief.bib is provided
% with glossaries-extra.sty
 src=example-glossaries-brief,
 selection=all
] 
\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

Document build should be:

```
pdflatex filename
bib2gls filename
pdflatex filename
```

Comment: I've just checked and Overleaf currently has `glossaries-extra` version 1.07 (2016/08/15) installed. (The log file shows TeX Live 2016/Debian.) At least version 1.08 (2016-12-13) is required for the `record` package option, although `bib2gls` works better with newer versions. Obviously `bib2gls` also needs to be installed as well, since it's part of the document build process. The initial release of `bib2gls` was 2017-09-09 so it won't be in TeX Live 2016.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Thanks Nicola!. I have checked the log file and it shows the following: "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.7.12)  13 DEC 2018 19:02". I'm using v2.overleaf which is a newer version

Comment: That's strange. I'm using v2 but getting "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.1.2)  13 DEC 2018 19:13". As far as I can tell, Overleaf using `latexmk` and there's [an example rc file for `bib2gls` on CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexmk/example_rcfiles/bib2gls_latexmkrc) which you could try uploading to your overleaf project directory.

Comment: Do I need to create a new file with a name bib2gls that contains the commands in the link above? I'm a beginner

Comment: @NicolaTalbot just to explain the behavior, depending on when the project you checked was created (or if it was copied from an older project), it may be set to use an older TeX Live image on Overleaf's servers, so that most probably explains the discrepancy here. (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.)

Comment: @PaulGessler Okay. Thank you for clarifying that. Is `bib2gls` installed on Overleaf? I've tried creating a new simple project with the example latexmk file in my earlier link but there's no indication of `bib2gls` running.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I don't think so (I don't think it made it into our cut of TL2017), but I might be wrong, so I've asked some colleagues of mine to confirm before answering definitively.

Comment: I asked the support team and they said that bib2gls is not installed on overleaf.

Comment: @Ali I've add a minimal working example to your question to make it easier to copy and paste for testing. I hope Overleaf consider adding bib2gls.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot The question is accurate now and deals specifically with the problem. Thanks for the editing

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Are you aware of any method that allows me to list all the abbreviations on a separate file and include them at the preamble file?

Comment: @Ali You can just create a `.tex` file containing `\newglossaryentry` or `\newabbreviation` and input them into the document (using `\input` or `\loadglsentries`). The [Introductory Guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/bib2gls/bib2gls-begin.pdf) supplied with `bib2gls` starts with some general information that doesn't actually require bib2gls (or any other tool), which might help you get started.

Comment: @ali, @nicola-talbot, @paul-gessler Do you know if Overleaf has `bib2gls` now?

Comment: I've just tried to compile a project of mine which looks just like this MWE on Overleaf and, even though the Overleaf logs show that bib2gls is present, the same warnings are shown as in this post.

Comment: Using the [example `latexmkrc` file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexmk/example_rcfiles/bib2gls_latexmkrc) posted above by Nicola, it looks like it works to me.