# How to effectively use List of Symbols for a thesis using .bib files?

Tags: table-of-contents, symbols, glossaries-extra

Actually, this question has been already asked here:
[How to effectively use List of Symbols for a thesis?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348640/how-to-effectively-use-list-of-symbols-for-a-thesis)

And there is a very good answer with 4 methods.

However...

Thank you very much for the post, very interesting! I am trying to implement the method 4 on Overleaf.com, but I meet some problems... Would be someone so kind to help me?

I have followed the example here above creating a file 'greek-symbols.bib' exactly as described above. Then I have a created a "symbols.tex" file:

```
\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,
     record % using 'bib2gls'
]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
 src={greek-symbols},% entries in 'greek-symbols.bib'
 type=symbols,% put these entries in the 'symbols' glossary
 save-locations=false% don't save locations
]
```

In the main.tex, I call this file, the settings, and build the document (for example):

```
\input{head/settings.tex}  % place your packages, etc... in this file!
\input{symbols.tex}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables
% Symbols
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=long,title={List of Symbols}]

\chapter{Mathematics}
Some symbols
Reference symbols: $\gls{x}$, $\gls{v}$, $\gls{a}$, $\gls{t}$, $\gls{F}$.

\end{document}
```

But the problem is that I obtain the following error:

> Package gloassaries-extra Warning: No file 'output.glstex' on input
>   line 13.

If I look at line 13, it corresponds to the end of command

```
\GlsXtrLoadResources[
 src={greek-symbols},% entries in 'greek-symbols.bib'
 type=symbols,% put these entries in the 'symbols' glossary
 save-locations=false% don't save locations
]
```

What is going on? Why following strictly the example, it does not work?

I would be very thankful if someone can help me.

Best regards, Elfo

Comment: Unfortunately Overleaf currently doesn't support `bib2gls` see [Problem with the Glossary+bib2gls on Overleaf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464716).

Comment: Ooh Gosh! That explains a lot of things! This is the reason why the bibliography is not working then! Thanks a lot.
How to do then? Did you find a way to overcome that problem?

Comment: You could ask Overleaf if they're going to add support for `bib2gls`. Perhaps if enough people ask they may add it.

Comment: Hi Nicola, I have implemented the method 4 and it works perfectly! Thanks a lot! Would it be possible to use a similar method to create a glossary?

Comment: Actually I was thinking that method 4 could be used to generated a glossary that would contain symbols, acronyms, definitions, etc... as you show that you can separated latin symbols from greek symbols...

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple lists. There are some examples provided with `bib2gls` in the [`examples` subdirectory](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/bib2gls/examples). They're described in the "Examples" chapter of the manual. I'll see if I can provide an answer with an example.

Comment: Indeed, it might be good if you can provide an example as you showed previously for method 4. This was nicely done with example results! Awesome!

Comment: @Elfo2285 Nicola provided a really long answer that took hours to be prepared and written here. I think that the answer solves your problem and you should accept it. Users that doesn't accept answers after their problem is resolved, sometimes could have problems to find someone that would use its personal free time to help them because they seem to not respect that effort (and here the effort is unbelievable!). This is not a matter of points on the platform or on anything similar to points, but of making an answer more find-able and easier  extendable. It's a matter of respecting people's time

Comment: @koleygr. Hi! Yes, thanks for the reminder. It is not a matter of lazyness... it is that I haven't found the time to implement his answer!!! The last two months I was busy with experiments, now I am back at writing again. In the following days I shall implement his solution... which is amazing by the way! Thanks Nicola

Comment: Sorry, I didn't meant to press you accepting an answer before really test it, I just thought that you forgot to do it and tried to help you understanding how some things on this kind of "forums" work... Anyway I think that already your first tests about the method 4 that you said it works perfectly solves the problem of  the original question... So, it should be accepted and for additional requests you may always open a follow-up question and use everything you already learn to create a nice MWE with clear expectations on this new post... Happy TeXing...

Comment: @koleygr Hi. I followed your recommendation. I followed the answer of Nicola. I am almost there, but I still have some issues. Therefore, I opened a new [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480117/errors-in-using-list-of-symbols-for-a-thesis-using-bib-files) to finalize the example I've implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will demonstrate using some of the example `.bib` files provided with `bib2gls`.

[`mathgreek.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/bib2gls/examples/mathgreek.bib) defines some sample symbols that are all mathematical Greek characters. The LaTeX kernel doesn't provide commands for Greek characters that look the same as Latin character. This stems back to the days of limited resources and, for example, omicron could simply be produced with `$o$`. Unfortunately, from a sorting point of view this would result in omicron being placed between N and P instead of between Xi and Pi.

The interpreter used by `bib2gls` recognises the missing commands `\omicron` etc and so can correctly order them with the other math-Greek commands. However, it's necessary for LaTeX to also recognise them as well. The `glossaries-extra-bib2gls` package (automatically loaded with `\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}`) now provides these missing commands. The `mathgreek.bib` example file allows for an older version that doesn't provide them and uses `@preamble` to provide the definition of `\omicron`:

```
@preamble{"\providecommand{\omicron}{o}"}
```

The entries are defined using `@symbol`. The `identifier` field is a custom field that  `bib2gls` won't recognise by default, but it's possible to provide or alias the field on a per-document basis. This just makes the `.bib` file more widely useful across multiple documents. The first couple of entries are:

```
@symbol{alpha,
  name={\ensuremath{\alpha}},
  description={alpha},
  identifier={mathgreek}
}

@symbol{beta,
  name={\ensuremath{\beta}},
  description={beta},
  identifier={mathgreek}
}
```

The other entries follow the same format.

[`mathsobjects.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/bib2gls/examples/mathsobjects.bib) is rather more complicated. It first provides some semantic commands to format the notation:

```
@preamble{"\providecommand{\setfmt}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
\providecommand{\setcontentsfmt}[1]{\{#1\}}
\providecommand{\setmembershipfmt}[2]{\setcontentsfmt{#1: #2}}
\providecommand{\setmembershiponeargfmt}[1]{\setmembershipfmt#1}
\providecommand{\setcardfmt}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\providecommand{\numspacefmt}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\providecommand{\transposefmt}[1]{#1^T}
\providecommand{\invfmt}[1]{#1^{-1}}
\providecommand{\vecfmt}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\providecommand{\mtxfmt}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}"}
```

So, for example, `\setfmt` formats its argument in a calligraphic font to denote a set. The first three entries are defined as:

```
@symbol{set,
  name={\ensuremath{\setfmt{S}}},
  description={\sortart{a}{set}},
  format={setfmt},
  identifier={set}
}

@symbol{setcontents,
  name={\ensuremath{\setcontentsfmt{\ldots}}},
  description={set contents},
  format={setcontentsfmt},
  identifier={set}
}

@symbol{setmembership,
  name={\ensuremath{\setmembershipfmt{\vecfmt{x}}{\ldots}}},
  description={set membership},
  format={setmembershiponeargfmt},
  identifier={set}
}
```

The other entries are defined in a similar way. Again the custom `identifier` field is used, which `bib2gls` will ignore by default. There's also another custom field called `format` that's used to store the name of a control sequence that takes a single argument that applies the appropriate format. This will also be ignored by default.

[`baseunits.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/bib2gls/examples/baseunits.bib) uses a custom entry type (`@unit`), so `bib2gls` will ignore all entries in this file unless an alias is set up. This means that different documents using the same `.bib` file can use whatever's the most appropriate entry type. For example, if a document needs `@unit` to be treated as `@symbol`, then the document needs to set up the alias:

```
entry-type-aliases={unit=symbol}
```

or if `@unit` should be treated as `@entry`:

```
entry-type-aliases={unit=entry}
```

The first few entries are defined as:

```
@unit{ampere,
  unitname={ampere},
  unitsymbol={\si{\ampere}},
  measurement={electric current},
  identifier={baseunit}
}

@unit{kilogram,
  unitname={kilogram},
  unitsymbol={\si{\kilogram}},
  measurement={mass},
  identifier={baseunit}
}

@unit{metre,
  unitname={metre},
  unitsymbol={\si{\metre}},
  measurement={length},
  identifier={baseunit}
}
```

The other entries all follow the same format. In this case all the fields are custom fields that `bib2gls` will ignore by default, so they will need to be aliased. This again allows greater flexibility across multiple documents that use the same `.bib` file.

[`makruplanguages.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/bib2gls/examples/markuplanguages.bib) has a mixture of normal entries (`@entry`) and abbreviations (`@abbreviation`). This provides a custom command used to tag the abbreviation initials. This just does its argument by default:

```
@preamble{"\providecommand{\abbrvtag}[1]{#1}"}
```

The `.bib` file also defines a bib variable for convenience:

```
@string{markuplang="\abbrvtag{m}arkup \abbrvtag{l}anguage"}
```

This variable is just for use in the `.bib` file. String concatenation is performed with `#` in a `.bib` file. For example:

```
long = {e\abbrvtag{x}tensible } # markuplang
```

is equivalent to:

```
long = {e\abbrvtag{x}tensible \abbrvtag{m}arkup \abbrvtag{l}anguage}
```

The first few entries are:

```
@entry{TeX,
  name={{}\TeX},
  description={a format for describing complex type and page layout
    often used for mathematics, technical, and academic publications},
  identifier={markuplanguage}
}

@entry{LaTeX,
  name={{}\LaTeX},
  description={a format of \glstext{TeX} designed to separate
   content from style},
  identifier={markuplanguage}
}

@entry{markdown,
  name={markdown},
  description={a lightweight markup language with plain text
    formatting syntax},
  identifier={markuplanguage}
}

@abbreviation{xml,
  short={XML},
  long={e\abbrvtag{x}tensible }#markuplang,
  description={a markup language that defines a set of rules for
    encoding documents},
  identifier={markuplanguage}
}

@abbreviation{html,
  short={HTML},
  long={\abbrvtag{h}yper\abbrvtag{t}ext }#markuplang,
  description={the standard markup language for creating web pages},
  identifier={markuplanguage}
}
```

The empty group `{}` in front of `\TeX` and `\LaTeX` is in case any automated first letter upper-casing command is applied, as it's not appropriate for these commands.

Some of the sample `.bib` files use custom commands such as `\sortart`. There are three different `.bib` files that provide these commands: [`no-interpret-preamble.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/bib2gls/examples/no-interpret-preamble.bib), [`interpret-preamble.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/bib2gls/examples/interpret-preamble.bib) and [`interpret-preamble2.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/bib2gls/examples/interpret-preamble2.bib). For now, I'm just going to use `no-interpret-preamble.bib` which contains:

```
@preamble{"\providecommand{\sortname}[2]{#1 #2}
\providecommand{\sortvonname}[3]{#1 #2 #3}
\providecommand{\sortart}[2]{#1 #2}
\providecommand{\sortmediacreator}[2]{#1 #2}"}
```

The first example document just has a single list to get started. The `mathsobjects.bib` file includes commands that are provided by `amssymb`, and the `baseunits.bib` file includes commands that are provided by `siunitx`, so those packages will need to be loaded:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}

% always set the abbreviation style before \GlsXtrLoadResources
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short-desc}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={no-interpret-preamble,mathgreek,mathsobjects,baseunits,markuplanguages},% bib files
  sort={en-GB},% sort according to this locale
  entry-type-aliases={unit=entry},% make @unit behave like @entry
  field-aliases={
    unitname=name,
    unitsymbol=symbol,
    measurement=description
  },
  selection=all% select all entries in the .bib files
]

\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

If the file is called `test.tex` then the document build is:

```
pdflatex test
bib2gls test
pdflatex test
```

(Replace `pdflatex` with `xelatex` etc, as appropriate.)

This creates a single glossary that starts as follows:

[image: image of start of glossary]

This places beta (β) between "ampere" and "candela". The sort values are determined by the entry type. For example, if an entry is defined with `@entry` then the sort value is obtained from the `name` field, if an entry is defined with `@abbreviation` then the sort value is obtained from the `short` field, and if an entry is defined with `@symbol` then the sort value is obtained from the label. So β is actually sorted by its label `beta`.

You can change the field used to obtain the default sort value for the `@symbol` entries using the `symbol-sort-fallback` option. For example, to use the `name` field instead:

```
symbol-sort-fallback=name
```

(For abbreviations, you can use `abbreviation-sort-fallback`.) Below is a modified version of the above MWE that sorts symbols according to the `name` field:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}

% always set the abbreviation style before \GlsXtrLoadResources
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short-desc}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={no-interpret-preamble,mathgreek,mathsobjects,baseunits,markuplanguages},% bib files
  sort={en-GB},% sort according to this locale
  entry-type-aliases={unit=entry},% make @unit behave like @entry
  field-aliases={
    unitname=name,
    unitsymbol=symbol,
    measurement=description
  },
  symbol-sort-fallback=name,
  selection=all% select all entries in the .bib files
]

\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

The start of the glossary now looks like:

[image: image of start of glossary]

The Greek letters now come after Z:

[image: image of glossary from X to lambda]

There are a number of ways of splitting the data up into separate glossaries. This first method prevents the creation of the default `main` glossary (using the `nomain` package option) and defines three glossaries with labels that correspond to the entry type (without the initial `@`). This means that the type can easily be assigned using:

```
type={same as entry}
```

Here's the updated MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[record,nomain]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossary*{entry}{Glossary}
\newglossary*{abbreviation}{Abbreviations}
\newglossary*{symbol}{Symbols}

% always set the abbreviation style before \GlsXtrLoadResources
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short-desc}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={no-interpret-preamble,mathgreek,mathsobjects,baseunits,markuplanguages},% bib files
  sort={en-GB},% sort according to this locale
  entry-type-aliases={unit=entry},% make @unit behave like @entry
  field-aliases={
    unitname=name,
    unitsymbol=symbol,
    measurement=description
  },
  symbol-sort-fallback=name,
  type={same as entry},
  selection=all% select all entries in the .bib files
]

\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

The document now has three lists. The first is the `entry` glossary:

[image: image of glossary]

The second is the `abbreviation` glossary:

[image: image of list of abbreviations]

The third is the `symbol` glossary, which starts:

[image: image of start of symbol list]

The Greek characters again come after Z.

Unlike the `\makeglossaries` approach (using `makeindex` or `xindy`), this method only has two associated glossary files: the `.glstex` which is input by `\GlsXtrLoadResources` and the `.glg` transcript file (which contains messages from `bib2gls`). With `makeindex`/`xindy` a document that has three glossary lists would have 10 corresponding glossary files (3 per glossary plus the style file).

With `bib2gls`, it's not the number of glossaries but the number of `\GlsXtrLoadResources` commands that determines the number of associated glossary files. Here's an alternative to the above that uses two resource commands:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[record,abbreviations,symbols]{glossaries-extra}

% always set the abbreviation style before \GlsXtrLoadResources
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short-desc}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={no-interpret-preamble,markuplanguages},% bib files
  sort={en-GB},% sort according to this locale
  selection=all% select all entries in the .bib files
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={mathgreek,mathsobjects,baseunits},% bib files
  sort={letter-case},% sort according Unicode value
  entry-type-aliases={unit=entry},% make @unit behave like @entry
  field-aliases={
    unitname=name,
    unitsymbol=symbol,
    measurement=description
  },
  symbol-sort-fallback=name,
  type=symbols,
  selection=all% select all entries in the .bib files
]

\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

In this case, I've used the `abbreviations` and `symbols` package option to create the glossaries labelled `abbreviations` and `symbols`. Package options that are provided by the base `glossaries` package are processed before options that are only provided by `glossaries-extra`, so `\printunsrtglossaries` will now list the glossaries in the order: `main` (default), `symbols`, `abbreviations`. You can change the order by using `\printunsrtglossary` for each individual glossary. For example:

```
\printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations]
\printunsrtglossary % default main glossary
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols]
```

This method has the advantage that a different sort method can be used for the symbols list (`sort=letter-case`). The first resource command doesn't set the glossary with the `type` option, so the default type is used. This is the default `main` for normal entries, but the entries defined with `@abbreviation` in the `.bib` file are defined using `\newabbreviation` in the `.glstex` file, so they will end up in the `abbreviations` glossary, since the `abbreviations` package option has been used.

A glossary list can be sub-sorted in blocks by splitting the entries across multiple resource commands. For example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[record,abbreviations,symbols]{glossaries-extra}

% always set the abbreviation style before \GlsXtrLoadResources
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short-desc}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={no-interpret-preamble,markuplanguages},% bib files
  sort={en-GB},% sort according to this locale
  selection=all% select all entries in the .bib files
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={baseunits},% bib file
  sort={letter-case},% sort according Unicode value
  entry-type-aliases={unit=entry},% make @unit behave like @entry
  field-aliases={
    unitname=name,
    unitsymbol=symbol,
    measurement=description
  },
  symbol-sort-fallback=name,
  type=symbols,
  selection=all% select all entries in the .bib files
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={mathsobjects},% bib file
  sort={letter-case},% sort according Unicode value
  symbol-sort-fallback=name,
  type=symbols,
  selection=all% select all entries in the .bib files
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={mathgreek},% bib file
  sort={letter-case},% sort according Unicode value
  symbol-sort-fallback=name,
  type=symbols,
  selection=all% select all entries in the .bib files
]

\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

The symbols list now starts with the units:

[image: image of symbols list with units at the start]

In this case I've used `sort=letter-case` for all the sub-blocks, but it's possible to use different sort methods for each block.

Let's suppose I now want to switch to a glossary style that displays letter group headings, for example the `treegroup` style:

```
\usepackage[record,abbreviations,symbols,stylemods={tree},style=treegroup]{glossaries-extra}
```

Now `bib2gls` needs to be run with the `--group` (or `-g`) switch:

```
bib2gls --group test
```

If the above change is made to the MWE, this will result in errors like:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character  (U+1D6FC)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

This is because `bib2gls` tries to put the alpha entry into the "" letter group, but that Unicode character isn't supported by the document. However, in this case it isn't appropriate for each Greek letter to be in its own letter group. Instead the entire block can be assigned to its own group using the `group` option. The value must be a **label**. A title can be assigned using `\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{`*label*`}{`*title*`}`. For example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[record,abbreviations,symbols,stylemods={tree},style=treegroup]{glossaries-extra}

% always set the abbreviation style before \GlsXtrLoadResources
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short-desc}

% Assign group titles:
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{units}{SI Units}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{latin}{Latin Symbols}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{greek}{Greek Symbols}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={no-interpret-preamble,markuplanguages},% bib files
  sort={en-GB},% sort according to this locale
  selection=all% select all entries in the .bib files
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={baseunits},% bib file
  sort={letter-case},% sort according Unicode value
  entry-type-aliases={unit=entry},% make @unit behave like @entry
  field-aliases={
    unitname=name,
    unitsymbol=symbol,
    measurement=description
  },
  symbol-sort-fallback=name,
  type=symbols,
  group=units,
  selection=all% select all entries in the .bib files
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={mathsobjects},% bib file
  sort={letter-case},% sort according Unicode value
  symbol-sort-fallback=name,
  type=symbols,
  group=latin,
  selection=all% select all entries in the .bib files
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={mathgreek},% bib file
  sort={letter-case},% sort according Unicode value
  symbol-sort-fallback=name,
  type=symbols,
  group=greek,
  selection=all% select all entries in the .bib files
]

\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

The symbols list now starts:

[image: image of start of symbol list with group headings]

The custom `identifier` fields all have values that can be used as labels. It's possible to convert `identifier` into `group` using the option:

```
field-aliases={identifier=group}
```

The titles need to be supplied:

```
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{set}{Sets}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{numberspace}{Number Spaces}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{matrix}{Matrices and Vectors}
```

It's now necessary to sort according to the `group` field in order to keep the members of each group together. This can be done with the option:

```
sort-field={group}
```

Entries within the same group then need to be sorted according to the `name` field. There are two ways to do this.

1. Set `identical-sort-action={name}` which will perform a character code comparison on the `name` field when the compared sort values (obtained from the field identified by `sort-field`) are identical.
2. Use `sort-suffix={name}` which will append the value of the `name` field to the sort value.

I've used the first option below with `sort=en-GB`, which means that the sort value (obtained from the `group`) field will be sorted according to the `en-GB` collation rules and the `name` fields will be sorted according to character code (which makes more sense for symbols).

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[record,abbreviations,symbols,stylemods={tree},style=treegroup]{glossaries-extra}

% always set the abbreviation style before \GlsXtrLoadResources
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short-desc}

% Assign group titles:
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{units}{SI Units}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{set}{Sets}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{numberspace}{Number Spaces}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{matrix}{Matrices and Vectors}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{greek}{Greek Symbols}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={no-interpret-preamble,markuplanguages},% bib files
  sort={en-GB},% sort according to this locale
  selection=all% select all entries in the .bib files
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={baseunits},% bib file
  sort={letter-case},% sort according Unicode value
  entry-type-aliases={unit=entry},% make @unit behave like @entry
  field-aliases={
    unitname=name,
    unitsymbol=symbol,
    measurement=description
  },
  symbol-sort-fallback=name,
  type=symbols,
  group=units,
  selection=all% select all entries in the .bib files
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={mathsobjects},% bib file
  sort={en-GB},% sort according to this locale
  sort-field={group},% sort according to this field
  identical-sort-action={name},% sort using letter case comparison by this field when sort-field values are identical
  symbol-sort-fallback=name,
  type=symbols,
  field-aliases={identifier=group},
  selection=all% select all entries in the .bib files
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={mathgreek},% bib file
  sort={letter-case},% sort according Unicode value
  symbol-sort-fallback=name,
  type=symbols,
  group=greek,
  selection=all% select all entries in the .bib files
]

\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

The start of the symbols list now looks like:

[image: image of first page of symbols list]

There are [many predefined styles](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles/) to choose from.

### Acronyms vs Abbreviations

The base `glossaries` package provides the command `\newacronym` which may be used to define acronyms or other forms of abbreviations. The package options `acronyms` or `acronym` create a new glossary `acronym`. You can reference it explicitly with that label or use `\acronymtype`.

The `glossaries-extra` extension package provides a completely new abbreviation handling system that's more flexible than the one used by the base package. The `\newabbreviation` command is provided to define all forms of abbreviations (including acronyms) using this new mechanism.

To assist with migrating from just using the base package to using the `glossaries-extra` package, `\newacronym` is redefined in terms of `\newabbreviation`, but it also sets `category=acronym` (which overrides the default `category=abbreviation` set by `\newabbreviation`). It is possible to switch `\newacronym` back to using the base `glossaries` package's abbreviation handling, although I don't recommend this.

The `glossaries-extra` package also permits the `acronyms` or `acronym` package option, which can be used as well as or instead of the `abbreviations` package option. If you use both `acronyms`/`acronym` and `abbreviations` then (if no `type` is explicitly set) `\newacronym` will put the entry in the `acronym` (`\acronymtype`) glossary and `\newabbreviation` will put the entry in the `abbreviations` (`\glsxtrabbrvtype`) glossary. If you only use the `abbreviations` package option then `\acronymtype` is redefined to `\glsxtrabbrvtype`.

Within the `.bib` files, you may use either `@abbreviation` (which will define the entry using `\newabbreviation`) or `@acronym` (which will define the entry using `\newacronym`). Since `\newacronym` sets `category=acronym` by default, you need to use the optional argument of `\setabbreviationstyle` to set the abbreviation style. For example:

```
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
```

Comment: Hi Nicola, thank you very much for the answer! I will implement that in the following days (today I am busy), and let you know!

Comment: Could you define a list of acronyms in a .bib file instead of abbreviations? Can you define acronyms instead of abbreviations using this method? It would be more accurate to speak about acronyms instead of abbreviations...

Comment: @Elfo2285 Use `@acronym` instead of `abbreviation`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. I've learned a lot following these methods. I am almost there, but I still have some errors in the result. I've created test files to test what I would like to achieve. For that, I've opened a new [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480117/errors-in-using-list-of-symbols-for-a-thesis-using-bib-files) to finalize the glossary. Can you please help me?