# List of Symbols not updating with Overleaf

Tags: lists, glossaries, overleaf

I cannot get the List of Symbols updated, although I am making new entries. I am using the [`glossaries-extra` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra).

These are my predefined settings:

```
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{\symbolslistname} % Define Symbols List

\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}
\makeindex

\setglossarystyle{long}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

%Activation of Lists
\makeglossaries
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{glossdesc}{firstuc}
```

If I try to make a new entry like this:

```
\newglossaryentry{delta}{name=$\Delta$,description={Delta},sort=symboldelta,type=symbolslist}
```

It somehow doesn't refresh my List of Symbols.

Does anybody know what needs to be done?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/134641)! Have you tried using [the suggested `latexmk` glossaries configuration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1228/134641)? Also see [this Overleaf glossary compilation guide](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Glossaries#Compiling_the_glossary) and [`latexmk` guide](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/How_to_use_latexmkrc_with_Overleaf?).

Comment: You might also want to try this first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70723384/5339699

Comment: May be related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464716/134641